# Does the use of Django template tags execute Querysets?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-queryset

I'm reading the book Django 2 by Example and am getting confused at one point there's a line `{% with comments.count as total_comments %}` where the author goes on to explain

> **We are using the Django ORM in the template, executing the QuerySet `comments.count()`...The {% with %} template tag is useful to avoid
>   hitting the database or accessing expensive methods multiple times.**

I thought templates are using whatever context is passed to them and no database access occurs?

Comment: `QuerySet`s are lazy, and thus only performed when you "consume" these. So the template can be the "trigger" to perform the query "represented" by the `QuerySet`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I thought templates are using whatever context is passed to them and no database access occurs?

Well it uses what is passed through the context. But a `QuerySet` is performed *lazily*. That means that if you for example pass `MyModel.objects.all()` it will *not* make the query, or at least not immediately.

It is only when you "*consume*" the queryset, for example by iterating over it, or by calculating the length of the queryset, that you will make a query to the database. A template can thus trigger several database queries. In fact *N+1 problems* often are caused by templates that iterate over one `QuerySet` of objects, and then query over a  related manager as well.

A `.count()` on a `QuerySet` is evaluated eagerly as well, so if you have `somequeryset`, and you call `.count()` that will trigger a database query. If that is done in a loop, or at different locations in the template, then it will thus reduce in more queries to the database. By using a `{% with …=… %}` statement, you will make the query when the template evaluates the `{% with …=… %}` part, and then you can reuse that variable multiple times.